# signinwithphonenumber authentication failed

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am getting

> SigninwithPhoneNumber failed: expected 2 arguments but got 1

in this code

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then(confirmResult =>
    this.setState({ confirmResult, message: "Code has been sent!" })
  )
  .catch(error =>
    this.setState({
      message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}`
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: The error message is very clear https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone

Comment: but when i use recapcha verifier its show error second argument applicationverifier must be an implementation of firebase.auth.applicationverifier

Comment: Yes, so you need one of those

Comment: I also get an error that says ApplicationVerifier is only for browser. I'm using react-native like the OP here. Also https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/auth/phone-auth.md and https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth show examples with only one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to be providing two arguments to the signInWithPhoneNumber method. In the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone). You need to be providing a phone number and an app verifier.

```
firebase
 .auth()
 .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
```